# Install 2.4.33 kernel in Debian Wheezy

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, debian

I need to install old kernel into Kali (Debian like) distro. I need to run program which requires older kernel.

I downloaded kernel but the installation gives me too many errors. I was reading similar topics and watch the videos, but so far I am not successful.

I do not have experience with kernels. Is there .deb package for kernels or any other easier way to do it?

Can I use such old kernel for this distribution?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2.4.33 kernel is pretty old.  According to Debian's packaging files installing that old a kernel doesn't seem to be doable in wheezy.  Attempting to install and run an old kernel outside the packaging system is *not* going to to work.  All the "modern" libraries and applications *will be broken* when running the 2.4 kernel, as will the program (you need more than just a kernel for your program). If it were me, I'd set up a virtualization environment like [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) or something similar and pick an old distro like [CentOS 3.9](http://vault.centos.org/3.9/) or [an older Debian release](http://www.debian.org/distrib/archive) (sarge or later).  If that's not an option, you could always try and port the program to a more recent kernel.

Comment: This is what I am doing. I am installing Woody. It looks terrible so far. Very old, I guess I lost some nerves over time ;)